# Pip install doesn't install any .py files

Tags: python, python-3.x

**The issue:** I ran `pip install pyshp`, but could not import it into my python project. When I check the package in my site-packages folder, I see it installed as 'pyshp-2.1.0.dist-info'. When I look at what's inside that folder, I only see the following files: INSTALLER, LICENSE.txt, METADATA, RECORD, REQUESTED, top_level.txt, and WHEEL. I don't see a single .py file. When I download the package manually from the [pyshp download page](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/#files), the folder has a bunch of other files, including the shapefile.py file that I need. So it seems like the download is getting stuck somehow. I've also tested and encountered this same issue with Pillow and Matplotlib, so I think it's something with my Python setup, not an issue with the package itself.

I'm fairly new to Python, does anyone know what I've done wrong? Or any other ideas? Thanks for your help in advance.

**Edit**: To be clear, I'm not trying to fix the pyshp install issue directly, but instead figure out why the install process isn't working for all of the packages I'm trying to install.

Comment: What does `pip list` say? Can you find your package there?

Comment: Yes, it shows as pyshp with the correct version.

Comment: how you are importing? import pyshp?

Comment: import shapefile. The package is named pyshp but there is a file called shapefile.py that I need to import and use.

Comment: Are you trying to use python 2 or 3? Pip (for some reason) by default downloads/installs the py2 version of the library, which won't be recognized by a python 3 script. Use pip3 install instead if this is the case. The other thing I can think of is to try adding a version shebang to the top of your script (if not there already).

Answer (score -1):

Go to your site packages directory, it is in the root of the site packages directory. So copy and place it in the same directory beside your python script, and you can `import shapefile`

Comment: That would fix it for pyshp, but without fixing the underlying issue it'll affect all the other packages I try to import going forward. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the original question, I'll edit it to make that more clear.

Comment: @ConorBaumgart no it will not affect. When you installed pyshp, it only installed dist info directory and shapefile.py, and dist info is not too important for most of the cases, so you won't get any problem